# OpenSTV election results file has the wrong heading (always has current year)

Tags: bug, election-page

There have been a number of elections across Stack Exchange over the past years, and the voting data is available for the most of them (all of them?).

For each election, there's a link to the 'blt' ballot file for that election.

The last line of each file is the 'title' of the election, and for example, [the most recent election on User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election/2), has the results [available here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/2) with the title on the last line of the file: "User Experience Stack Exchange Moderator Election 2015"

```
.......
"Zoe Kulsariyeva"
"Benny Skogberg"
"DaveAlger"
"JohnGB"
"Vitaly Mijiritsky"
"Code Maverick"
"Evil Closet Monkey"
"Charles Wesley"
"3nafish"
"AEJBUG"
"User Experience Stack Exchange Moderator Election 2015"
```

**Bug**: The year in the title is always the current year, not the year the election happened in (even though the file name has the correct year...)

Consider these previous elections:

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election):

1. First 2011: https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/1 - "Stack Overflow Moderator Election **2015**" `stackoverflow-com-2011-election-results.blt` (Note the correct file name - 2011)
2. Second 2011: https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/2 - "Stack Overflow Moderator Election **2015**" - `stackoverflow-com-2011-election-results.blt` (Note the correct file name - 2011 - but duplicate filename)
3. Third 2012: https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/3 - "Stack Overflow Moderator Election **2015**" - `stackoverflow-com-2012-election-results.blt`

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/election):

1. First 2011: https://serverfault.com/election/download-result/1 - "Server Fault Moderator Election **2015**" - `serverfault-com-2011-election-results.blt`
2. Second 2012: https://serverfault.com/election/download-result/2 - "Server Fault Moderator Election **2015**" - `serverfault-com-2012-election-results.blt`

Comment: Thank good it's not only me having problem with that challanging piece of software :-)